# Python intra-package imports don't work at all

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, python-import, importerror

My directory structure is like the following:

```
toplevel/
    subdir/
        __init__.py
        foo/
          __init__.py
          foo.py
        bar/
          __init__.pt
          bar.py
```

if i try to `from foo import foo` in bar.py, and execute bar.py from `subdir` with `python3 bar/bar.py` it says foo was not found. I used `os.getcwd()` and it is `toplevel/subdir`, so it should work. I've tried relative imports, but none work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Comment: ever wonder why `__init__.py` file is used /

Answer (score 0):

If you must do this, you can use `sys.path` to see what paths interpreter can load module from.

and then via `sys.append('path you want add')` to add path